# `ng-hide` - Animation how to prevent a jump on hide?

Tags: css, angularjs

i am trying to do a accordion animation using `ng-hide` by the panels height. But I am finding a jump while the `ng-hide` applied. ( click on first title to show and hide )

any one help me to sort this issue please?

here is my css code :

```
.animate-show{
  border:2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  background:green;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:0;

}
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HenhNf4VbhUarIJNi1xr?p=preview)

Comment: have you forgot to include dependency to ng-animate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the margin between the green content `div` and the subsequent toggling div in the `.animate-show.ng-hide` class. You can do this by setting a negative `margin-bottom` styling to this class:

```
h1{
  background:gray;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.animate-show{
  border:2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  background:green;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-remove
{
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}


.animate-show.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:0;
  margin-bottom:-21px;
}
```

Here is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XQ4p8uE47QxQbDKUiIyi?p=preview

Comment: I agree with you. But what is that `-21px`, from where you calculate that?

Comment: That's just the margin specified for the grey boxes. It is 21.44px to be exact. Open up the console after visiting here: http://plnkr.co/edit/2nGOveBHoFB6cg4KnYR4?p=preview